RegEx for 3 characters and 7 numbers with no special characters
I am still learning to do regex, but this one gets me stumped for a while. I am trying to make a regex expression to match the strings like TOL1234567 or tol1234567. There should be 'TOL' at the first and then there will be 7 numbers after. No special characters are needed.
^(?=(?:[tolTOL])(((?=(?:[^0-9\r\n]*[0-9]){7}))$ - it doesn't work well. :(
I appreciate any help. Thank you!

[tolTOL] matches only 1 of those characters. what you probably needed was just either (tol|TOL) or just tol if you're using case insenstivity.

You could probably just get away with ^(tol|TOL)\d{7}$

/TOL|tol\d{7}/gm

TOL/tol - matches the TOL or tol string literally
\d - matches a digit [0-9]
\d{7} - matches a digit 7 times
you can use https://regex101.com to test your regexp
